# How to create an application bundle in Xcode?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, app-bundle

Alright, I have just finished coding an application in Xcode...  How do I create an application bundle out of this?  I tried using the "Release" build configuration, but on a tester's computer the application states that the application requires a newer version of OS X.  He has the latest one!  This is my info.plist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>Icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.huzzahgames.swfopener</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.6</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you building using the iOS SDK? Those apps won't work on the Mac. Otherwise, does the build succeed? If you go through the bundle and compare to this document: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW13 What's missing? If Info.plist is present, what does it contain (edit this into your question)?

Comment: If you are indeed building a Mac OS app (not an iOS app), then what version of OS X is your friend running?

Comment: He is running mac os 10.6.4.  And(chuckle) yes, this is cocoa, not iOS.  I will edit my info.plist into my question now.

Comment: The LSMinimumSystemVersion key (set to 10.6) seems right. I've never known this to reject an okay system wrongly (rather the reverse is true - depending on the versions in play, your app may simply crash without the kind warning). Best to paste the exact error message your friend is seeing (and double-check his/her system version).

Comment: I would try 10.6.0 just to be safe...